# Swift 5 programmatic segue not firing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to programmatically trigger a segue to a new View Controller based on whether or not a user is logged in.  I have based my code on the answer at [Performing a completion handler before app launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845347/performing-a-completion-handler-before-app-launches)

I've created a text button with the segue but it never fires. The print("Logged In") line functions, just not the segue.  I want my buttons to be disabled to prevent accidental taps, but having it enabled or disabled makes no difference to its firing.

My code in InitialViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkLoginStatus()
}

func checkLoginStatus() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isLoggedIn = defaults.bool(forKey: "loggedIn")

    if (isLoggedIn == true) {
        print("Logged In")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeController", sender: self)
    }

    else {
        print("Not Logged In")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginController", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do it in `didLoad`, do it `didAppear`

Comment: If you're doing a segue in code, it should be one that's attached to the view controller, not to a button.

Comment: How do I attach the segue to the VC??  I can't do it in the Storyboard, must I do it programmatically?

Comment: you don't need to do a segue. you can use `present(_:animated:completion:)`

Comment: @PhillipMills An action segue belongs to the view controller every bit as much as any other segue. It is perfectly normal to trigger an action segue using `perform`. Indeed, that is one reason segues have names! Otherwise you'd have to have two identical segues, one for when the user taps a button and one for when you want to trigger it in code, and that would be crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a segue from one view controller to another one in Storyboard this way:

1. Tap and hold right-click from `View Controller` property to assign it to another view controller inside of your storyboard this way:

[image]

2. Choose the type of presentation in `Manual Segue` section and tap on it:

[image]

3. Give an identifier to the newly created segue ("HomeController" or "LoginController" in your case):

[image]

4. Remove your old segue that is triggered on a button tap.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it helped :) @Glenn